# LNK1104 cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'

Tags: visual-studio-2022, kernel32

Getting following error LNK1104 cannot open file 'kernel32.lib', what path do i need to add, and where to add it in Visual Studio 2022.

I looked at previous threads, most solutions are for older versions of Visual Studio, can't find the configurations in newer version of Visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have installed the required [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/).
`kernel32.lib` is part of a [Windows Kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842484/what-are-windows-kits-and-how-do-they-work).

Example path from my Windows 10 system:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.20348.0\um\x64\kernel32.Lib
```

Visual Studio configuration `Project > Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories` might be broken. Restore it to `$(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)`.

Comment: I have the Windows SDK installed, and found kernel32.lib in the folder, i changed the Visual Studio configuration to include WindowsSDK, but didnt fix it, still getting same error.